# The value of x for which this series converge:

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to evaluate the $$\sum_0^{\infty}{(n + 1 + 2^n)x^n}.$$

PS - I am sorry. I am not sure how to write summation

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: The question is not in the correct format so a little bit unclear. From my understanding, the series will converge if and only if $x=0$

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: Hints: $\sum_0^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\sum_0^{\infty}nx^n=x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sum_0^{\infty}x^n\right)$

Answer (score 2):

We define $a_n= n+1+2^n$.

By the quotient criteria you get $$\frac {a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}=x\frac {n+2+2^{n+1}}{n+1+2^n}=x\frac{\frac n{2^{n+1}}+2^{-n}+1}{\frac n{2^{n+1}}+2^{-n-1}+\frac 12}\to 2x\,(n\to\infty)$$

So the series converges for $x<\frac 12$ and diverges for $x>\frac 12$.

For $x=\frac 12$ we get the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1+2^n)2^{-n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n2^{-n}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1=+\infty $$

Answer (score 1):

You may expand as follows to find the sum in compact form.

$$\sum_0^{\infty}{(n + 1 + 2^n)x^n}=\sum_0^{\infty}nx^n+\sum_0^{\infty}x^n+\sum_0^{\infty}(2x)^n.$$

To find the interval of convergence, use the ratio test, and check the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Take a closer look at the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1+2^{n})x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^{n}
\end{align*}
Then observe that the second summand is a geometric series which converges when $|2x| < 1$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^{n+1} = (n+1)x^{n}
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?